# Iframe element access by Id giving null

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The html is like this

```
<iframe id="MainFrame">
  <div id="Maintest">This is main text
        <div id ="SecondTest">This is second layer 
            <div id="ThirdTest">This is third layer</div>
        </div> 
  </div>
</iframe>
```

The javascript to access elements in frame is like this

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('MainFrame');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    console.log(iframe);
    var mydiv = innerDoc.getElementById("Maintest");
    console.log(mydiv);
    var seconddiv = innerDoc.getElementById("SecondTest");
    var thirddiv = innerDoc.getElementById("ThirdTest");
    console.log(seconddiv+thirddiv);
```

mydiv, seconddiv as well as thirddiv give null.I have seen on many posts that this is the way to access iframe element.I dont know why its giving null.Help appreciated.

Thanks
Swaraj

Comment: What does: `console.log(iframe.outerHTML);` give you?

Comment: @ChrisHardie It gives me this                                           

<iframe id="MainFrame">
  <div id="Maintest">This is main text
        <div id ="SecondTest">This is second layer 
            <div id="ThirdTest">This is third layer</div>
        </div> 
  </div>
</iframe>

Comment: Then this should work: iframe.outerHTML.getElementById("Maintest")

Comment: @Diodeus This does not work.TypeError: iframe.outerHTML.getElementById is not a function
 

var mydiv =  iframe.outerHTML.getElementById("Maintest") ;

Comment: You cannot provide content to an `<iframe>` that way. The code isn't working because the browser does not consider those elements as really being there, inside the frame.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks.Can you describe what u said in terms of code(html change to indicate that).Thanks

Comment: Is the problem with having div inside frame when it should be other way round i.e an iframe inside a div.Thanks.

Comment: Well `<iframe>` elements can contain entire documents, but  that's either loaded from a URL (via the "src" attribute, or because the frame is referenced as the "target" of a link or form), or else written via Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation for using an iframe is incorrect, I believe.  Any content within `<iframe>` tags is what would be displayed for a browser that does not support iframes.  There are only two ways to insert content into an iframe that I'm aware of:

`<iframe src="/example/content.html">Your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>`

and using javascript to append child nodes to the iframe using your innerDoc reference, such as:

`innerDoc.body.appendChild(child_ref);`

**UPDATE:**

Just to be clear, the html content you want to reference within your iframe needs to be in a separate file, such as `my_content.html` and the iframe needs to reference that file in the "src=" field, like: `<iframe src="my_content.html">`.

Comment: Got it working.That is the html but still mydiv,seconddiv,thirddiv give out null.i.e still innerdoc.getElementsById(divId) give out null.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre - If you're still having trouble, take a look at the update to my answer.  I hope it helps.

Comment: @EmoMosley.The html renders properly but I cannot access the divs inside the iframe.I move the content of Iframe to a different html and referenced it via src="iframe.html"where iframe.html has all the divs.But I cannot access the divs with the methods I have used before.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre - OK - I think the issue is that the javascript may be executing before the page has been loaded.  Try putting the code inside a function and call that function using <body onload="myfunc()">